# How to correctly discard a web post async c#

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, post

I have a number of web posts inside my application that need to send text data to a server but other than awaiting completion of the post shouldnt hold up the methods that are called from (large data posts that would slowdown logic etc that shouldnt be).

Currently im discarding the task as that appeared to be the correct method however on the server end logs indicate it seams to be closing the connection before the data is successfuly sent meaning I'm loosing most of the data in transit.

```
private void DoSomethingandPost()
{
        BeforeMethod();    
        PushWebDataAsync(TheData1);
        PushWebDataAsync(TheData2);
        AfterMethod();
}


public static async void PushWebDataAsync(string Data)
{
        ...makes changes to the data...
        try
        {
                _ = pushDataAync(Data);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
                 _ = pushDataAync(Data);
        }
}

public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Xml.XmlNode> pushDataAync(string Data)
{
        return base.Channel.pushDataAync(Data);
}
```

My gut feeling is that if "AfterMethod" returns before the data has completed sending the connection to the server is cut and so the data isnt fully transmitted.

What Im trying to acheieve really is DoSomethingandPost() completes and exits but the two async Post's continue on their own until complete then exit.

Comment: What if the calls fail? Do you need to compensate for that in your logic, or will you just ignore the errors?

Comment: currently its wrapped the call in a try catch and just trys a second time. its a very basic data post so only network conditions / a server being down should cause issues.

updated the example code

Answer (score 1):

If `AfterMethod` must run after the two `PushWebDataAsync` calls, then make the later return a Task, make `AfterMethod` async and await the push-methods. `DoSomethingandPost` will return at the first await-statement, doing the rest of the work at some later time . If you want to do the push concurrently then do

```
var task1 = PushWebDataAsync(TheData1);
var task2 = PushWebDataAsync(TheData2);
await Task.WhenAll(new []{task1, task2});
...
```

It is good practice to avoid `async void` since this makes it impossible for the caller to know if the call succeeded or not. If you know this will never be needed, like in the event handler for a button, then it is good practice to handle any exception that may be thrown.